# como imprimir todas las palabras que tengan letras repetidas dentro de una cadenas. java

Tags: java

```
static void tar15() {
    String str[]= {"Nanny","Bob","and","Bill","Live", "in","Alabama"};
    String new_str="";

    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++) 
        for(int j=i; j<str[i].length(); j++){
            if(str[i].indexOf(str[i].charAt(j))>0);
            new_str+=str[i];
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(new_str);
}
```

se que el if no esta bien pero no se como hacer para que me imprima 
"Nanny,Bob,Bill,Alabama" que son las palabras que tienen letras repetidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, puedes recorrer el array y luego, recorrer cada palabra con dos bucles. Ten en cuenta que Bob no concidirá, ya que B es distinto de b.

```
String str[]= {"Nanny","Bob","and","Bill","Live", "in","Alabama"};
        String new_str="";

        for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){ //Recorrer el array 
             for(int j=0; j < str[i].length(); j++){
                 for (int k=0; k < str[i].length();k++){                         
                    if ( j != k && str[i].charAt(j) == (str[i].charAt(k)) ) {                      
                      new_str+=str[i]+","; 
                      k = str[i].length();
                      j = str[i].length();                  
                    }

                  }
             }
        }
        System.out.println(new_str);
```

Comment: mmm y  como podría hacer para que sí saliera, tipo pensé en hacer todas las letras de la cadena minúsculas y ahí empezar a preguntar. pero no se si hay otra forma.

Comment: Pasando todos los caracteres de los string a minúsculas o mayúsculas. Para minúsculas, en el if, podrías comprobarlo así :
  if ( j != k && str[i].toLowerCase().charAt(j) == (str[i].toLowerCase().charAt(k)) )

Comment: esta buena la idea, gracias lo voy a intentar

Comment: mill gracias< si funciono !!

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String str[]= {"Nanny","Bob","and","Bill","Live", "in","Alabama"};

        for(int i = 0; i< str.length; i++){

            char[] chars = str[i].toLowerCase().toCharArray();

            Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for(char c : chars) 
            {
                if(map.containsKey(c)) {
                    int counter = map.get(c);
                    map.put(c, ++counter);
                } else {
                    map.put(c, 1);
                }
            }

            int counter = 0;
            for(char c : map.keySet()) {
                if(map.get(c) > 1 && !Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                    counter++;    
                }
            }

            if(counter > 0){
                System.out.println("Palabra con letras repetidas "+str[i]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Puedes ver el codigo original sin modificar en [Java – Find duplicate characters in String](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/find-duplicate-characters/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer dos for each. Uno para string en el arreglo y otro para cada character en el string. De ahi con un poco de lambda magic puedes contar si un character se repite mas de una vez. Si la cuenta es mayor que 1, añades esa palabra (el string) a tu string de retorno. Está función retorn un solo string separado con comas de las palabras que tienen letras repetidas.

```java
     private void letrasRepetidas(String[] str) {
        String data = "";
        for (String text:str) {
            char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
            for (char character:chars) {
                long count = text.codePoints().filter(ch -> Character.toLowerCase(ch) == Character.toLowerCase(character)).count();
                if (count > 1) {
                    data = data + text + ",";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //esto borra la ultima comma
        data = data.substring(0, data.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
```

Luego lo llamas así:

```java
        String str[] = {"Nanny","Bob","and","Bill","Live", "in","Alabama"};
        letrasRepetidas(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te ofrezco una solución con dos bucles for: Uno para recorrer la lista de palabras y otro para recorrer la palabra y recuperar el char.

También utilizo dos HashSet.  El HashSet no permite tener duplicados, así es fácil comprobar si un character ya está en la palabra o no.  No he podido comprobar el método "filter" de la solución que te han ofrecido, pero parece que por debajo también está haciendo un for, por lo que ya es menos eficiente.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Receive by param
    List<String> allWords = new ArrayList<>();
    allWords.add("Character");
    allWords.add("Pig");
    allWords.add("All");

    HashSet<String> duplicatedWords = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<Character> duplicatedChars;

    for (String word : allWords) {
        duplicatedChars = new HashSet<>();
        // Extract in method to search the duplicated word
        for (Character character : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            boolean isDuplicated = duplicatedChars.contains(character);

            if (isDuplicated) duplicatedWords.add(word);
            else duplicatedChars.add(character);
        }
    }

    // Extract in method to show the result
    for (String duplicatedWord : duplicatedWords) {
        System.out.println(duplicatedWord);
    }
}
```